# Invert text color using glBlendFunc in Cocos2d on CCLabelTTF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add a CCLabelTTF to my Cocos2d project and have the text be an inverted version of the graphics behind it.

I am having a hard time figuring out what blend fund to use.
I have to admit I do not really understand the concepts behind this, so I am basically just trying different modes.

I have tried several types:

This one inverts the background of the text, but leaves the text white:

```
[fontLabel setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_ALPHA}];
```

Can you help me in the right direction?
I want the text to be inverted, and the background to be invisible.

Answer (score 4):

You can visually experiment with the various blendfunc methods with the aptly named [Visual glBlendFunc tool](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php).

You should also be aware that CCLabelTTF uses 8-Bit (alpha mask, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_A8) textures on 1st and 2nd generation devices, and 16-Bit (alpha+intensity mask, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_AI88) textures on 3rd generation and newer devices. This may or may not affect the blend mode results, or even make it impossible because the textures don't contain color information, only alpha.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done using glBlendFunc. Blending equation looks like this:

```
result = A * front_color  OP  B * back_color;
```

OpenGL allows you to configure A, B  - `glBlendFunc(A, B);`

and OP (operation) - `glBlendEquation(OP);`

To invert colors, you need

```
result = 1 - back_color;
```

You can do that by setting A = 1, B = 1, OP = FUNC_SUBTRACT, but you will have to set front_color to (1,1,1,1) in fragment shader.

P.S. I might be wrong, so write a comment below and I will change my answer.